# Suppressing eyediagram() function's figure

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, calling the `eyediagram()` function causes a figure to be created. Is there a way to not show the figure?

The arguments needed are internal to one of my functions. Which means, I have to use eyediagram() inside that function, and if a figure is going to show up I have to rename the title right after calling that function.

Is there a way to display the figure at some other place in the code.

Comment: According to the documentation `eyediagram`s only purpose is to plot something. I guess what you really want is to delete the call to this function altogether!

Comment: I want to save the data for the plot and do the plot somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ugly hack, but you can disable Matlab's plotting before running the eye() function and re-enable it after the function. Something like the following might work:

```
set(0,'DefaultFigureVisible','off');
eyediagram(...);
saveas(gcf, 'myfig', 'fig');    # save it in a file myfig.fig
set(0,'DefaultFigureVisible','on');
```

And when you want to show it

```
open('myfig.fig')
```

You can probably come up with a method that won't require saving to a file -- but the above should get you started...